# Cannot import Twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I installed Twython 1.2 using the Windows installer at this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twython/1.2. The installer seems to run fine.

I get the error "ImportError: cannot import name Twython" when I try to do:

```
from twython import Twython
from twython import TwythonStreamer
```

Does anybody know why I cannot import twython?

Answer (score 2):

Mmmm, Twython's current version is 3.x.x, not 1.2. I think that 1.2 installer is from yeaaars ago when I first started the project - the Twython API and structure has changed a ton since then.

Comment: I doubt that will cause an ImportError.

Comment: Pay attention to the question he asked - the Twython that can't be imported is with a capital T; it found the installed library, but the internal structure is different in 1.2. I would know, considering I built the damn thing and put the change in question into effect.

Comment: ok, got it now..but the op doesn't seem to reply or accept anything that is being said here..

Comment: @RyanMcGrath +1 for being an independent developer that actually helps their users; good work!

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` to point to the path containing the file `twython.py`. I'm not sure exactly where Twython installs itself, but presumably it told you during the installation. If not, search for the file `twython.py`, and the directory it's in is the one you want. I'm not sure how you're running your Python script that imports Twython. If it's from the DOS prompt, try something like

```
set PYTHONPATH="c:\Program Files\Twython1.2\SOMEDIR"
```

substituting the actual directory containing `twython.py` (which might not be in c:\Program Files).

If you're running your script graphically, then if you're running inside some sort of Python IDE, it might have a way of setting `PYTHONPATH` in its Preferences. Otherwise, you need to go to the Control Panel and find the place where you can set environment variables. It's been awhile since I've used Windows and things have changed recently but it might be under `Startup` or similar, then under `Advanced...` or similar.